# Error while installing ember cli app

Tags: ember.js, npm, frontend, broccolijs

i'm trying to install fresh cloned ember-cli app and getting this error.

```
Cannot find module 'ember-cli/lib/broccoli/get-ember-app' Error: Cannot find module 'ember-cli/lib/broccoli/get-ember-app'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dudasupport/duda3/DudaRoot/client/src/dashboard/Brocfile.js:2:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

Ember-cli is installed in node_modules but and broccoli directory presents there but there is no get-ember-app file. What can cause this?

Comment: did you run `npm install` and `bower install` and you could try reinstalling ember cli globally `npm uninstall ember-cli -g` and then reinstall it

Comment: yep. there is no global ember-cli installed.. :\

Comment: You need a global `ember-cli` installed @Boltosaurus, can you try it again after installing it?